# Submit form using jQuery get response from Perl script

Tags: jquery, perl

I just need a simple example on how to submit a form to a Perl script and get a simple response back, I think this sample code is missing something, and I can't figure it out. If someone could tell if this is a good way to start or where the issue is, thanks for the help.
Here is what I am using:
The html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4   /strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery.post demo</title>
<script src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

// Stop form from submitting normally
event.preventDefault();

// Get some values from elements on the page:
var $form = $( this ),
namev     = $form.find( "input[name='name']" ).val(),
agev      = $form.find( "input[name='age']" ).val(),
url       = $form.attr( "action" );
alert(url);

// Send the data using post
var posting = $.post( url, { name: namev, age: agev } );

// Put the results in a div
posting.done(function( data ) {

//var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );

$( "#result" ).empty().append( data );

});

});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<p>jQuery.post</p>

<form action="form_1.pl" id="searchForm">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search...">
<input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Perl test file:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $c = new CGI;

print $c->header();

if ('POST' eq $c->request_method && $c->param('name')) {

# yes, parameter exists
# print $c->param('name');
my $name = $c->param('name');
my $age = $c->param('age');

print "<span style='color:red'>Welcome <b>$name</b>. So you're <b>$age</b> years old eh?</span>";

 }else {

  print "--";

 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks correct, can you see any response at all? Is apache set up to execute CGIs?

Comment: Why such an ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: "I think this sample code is missing something, and I can't figure it out" - That's not a very useful description of your problem. Why do you think something is missing? What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Is there anything in the web server error log?

Comment: The form once submitted its just going to the perl script and not displaying the results back form the perl script in the <div id="result"></div>

Comment: @Andre Open the developer tools for your browser and reload the page. Check that 1) the request is sent to the correct URL and contains all the parameters you expect it to and 2) you get a valid response from your Perl script that contains the content you expect, and not an HTTP error. Update your post with your findings and we can help you troubleshoot further.

Comment: I edited my post, I wrapped the code with $( document ).ready(function() { ... }); and now it works like it should, but thanks!

Comment: @Andre Please don't edit your original post to show your solution. That makes it confusing for anybody who visits this page in the future and can't duplicate your (now non-existent) problem. Instead, you should create an answer saying how you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the code with

```
$( document ).ready(function() { ... });
```

and now it works like it should.

<sub>(Self-answered by Andre in the comments)</sub>